# Can I install GCC 4.4.4 on Fedora 29 or downgrade my Fedora version?

Tags: virtualbox, fedora, gcc

I have a piece of code that is currently compiling on Fedora 13 (I have it on a VM). I created a new VM using Fedora 29. The issue is that F29 has GCC v8.1 whereas the F13 has GCC v4.4.4 because of which the code is not compiling on F29. I found that using update-alternatives I can install multiple GCC versions. However, I am not able to install gcc4. Does anyone know, how to do it? Or, shall I use some other Fedora version (since the F13 doesn't allow me to install Virtual Box extensions).

I am using Virtual Box 6. I have no idea as I am new to all this.

Comment: downgrade to which fedora version? I cannot upgrade the code as its some legacy code that I am not allowed to modify. Hence the pain.

Comment: @Biswapriyo sorry, I can't do anything to the code at all. It is beyond my module. There is another team that handles that code and they are not ready to modify it, due to the code change involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using [podman](https://developers.redhat.com/articles/podman-next-generation-linux-container-tools/) to run a container inside of which you install gcc 4.4. You could either install it from scratch, *or* you could choose to use a CentOS 6 container — RHEL 6 used GCC 4.4.x, and so CentOS 6 does too. And unlike Fedora 13, it's still getting security updates.

This is super-easy:

```
podman run -it centos:6 /bin/bash
```

You don't need root or anything — but the above will drop you to a root shell inside the CentOS 6 environment, from which you can `yum install gcc`.

Comment: I ran the command and now I am in the root shell of some kind. I guess its the centos environment as you told. but now where do I see the code I have and also, I need 32 bit gcc. what shall I do now?

Comment: Look at the `podman` options for mounting in directories from the host to see your code. And use `i386/centos:6` to get a 32-bit version. You may want to investigate creating your own custom container with gcc preinstalled and configured as an entrypoint to run rather than using it as a lightweight VM — you'd use `buildah` to do that.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was able to get the 32 bit version and access the host folders as well. However, `yum install gcc` doesn't work and gives some errors regarding the 64bit library dependency. Not sure why, wll try the `buildah` option and see.